# WP Action center on WPF .net 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, touch, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to replicate the way the action center on windows phone 8.1 is shown in WPF on a touch enabled windows 7 version.

What I want is:
In my WPF app I want a control that the user can manipulate in Y direction in the same way the action center is manipulated. So this means that at a certain Y position the panel should be dropped to the bottom (but this needs to be gentle, not like y = 800, it needs to have a visual motion) the same goes for the y in a upwards direction. The control should be able to show all kind of other controls (for example, label, panel, textboxes). I don't need the notification abilitiy that windowsphone has. I'm just looking for the visual aspect).

What have i tried:
I've tried using the following event handlers on different controls:
TouchEnter
TouchLeave
TouchMove
ManipulationDelta

and i've also looked into the Surface Control SDK, but i found nothing of use there.

The problem is that i don't know where to look, i've tried different tocuh methods but i'm not really into touch so i don't know what method is the best one for my problem. Thats why i've come here for advice/anwsers.

My question,
What touch event/method do i need to replicate the windowsphone action center visuals, and how (and on what kind of control) do i use them?

(PS, i prefer C# but am also able to cope with VB)

(for the peeps that have no idea what the action center on windowsphone is. I've found this youtube video showing its use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hbb1Smqv24E

For me, I only need the swipe from top motion to show a panel or a grid or something).

Comment: Your repeated mentions of *the action center on windows phone 8.1* will only help users that are aware of that to understand your problem. Instead, try supplying a screenshot and further descriptions of what you want, so that other users may be able to help you too.

Comment: Action center is like Android or IOS notification center that opens by swiping from the top of the screen.

Comment: @Xmashallx, exactly!

Comment: @Sheridan I've added a video of the wp8.1 action center.